# Doxygen is skipping files with php __construct()

Tags: php, codeigniter, doxygen

I'm developing a web site using codeigniter framework. To document it, I've installed doxygen. Something weird is happening when doxygen meets files with the following structure:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * @class
 * @brief The class brief 
 */
  class Catalogo extends CI_Controller {    
    public function __construct(){         
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalogomodel');
        $this->load->library('img');
   }
    public function foo(){
       ..some code..
    }
/* End of file catalogo.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/catalogo.php */
```

This is the only files that are been skipped, other files with the usual structure in codeigniter are documented as they should.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * @class
 * @brief The class brief 
 */
  class Catalogo extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
      ...some code to load models, libraries and views ...
    }
   /* End of file catalogo.php */
   /* Location: ./application/controllers/catalogo.php */
```

Comment: Have you tried a docblock before `__construct()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how closely the examples you provided match your actual application, but for the original example code above:

Your class declarations do not appear to be closed (missing `}`). This will prevent doxygen from parsing the class declaration, and it will be skipped. Adding the closing `}` allows doxygen to fully parse the class, and it should be included in the documentation, however no documentation will appear for the class or its member functions, and `__construct` will not be listed as a member function.

Once this change is made, Doxygen 1.8.0 reports two warnings while processing the contents:

```
catalogo.php:6: warning: Compound Catalogo is not documented.
catalogo.php:13: warning: Member foo() (function) of class Catalogo is not documented.
```

The first is related to the empty `@class` markup. Doxygen expects `@class` to be immediately followed by the class name that the comment applies to, and is typically used when the doxygen is not located next to the construct it describes. In this case, `@class` can be removed since the `Catalogo` class declaration immediately follows it. Alternatively, you can also specify `@class Catalogo` explicitly. Making this change will silence the first warning, and will cause the documentation for `Catalogo` to appear in the doxygen output, however `__construct` will still be absent and `foo` will not be linked to a detailed description.

To address the second warning, you'll need to provide documentation for `foo`, something like:

```
/**
 * Documentation for foo.
 */
public function foo(){
}
```

This change will cause `foo` to appear in the documentation with a link to its detailed description. `__construct` will still not be present, however adding similar documentation for it:

```
/**
 * Documentation for __construct.
 */
public function __construct() {         
}
```

causes both functions to appear with links to their detailed descriptions. This all assumes a default doxygen configuration (`doxygen -g`) and Doxygen 1.8.0. The final code I tested (and which appears to work fine) was:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * @brief The class brief 
 */
class Catalogo extends CI_Controller {
    /**
     * Documentation for __construct.
     */
    public function __construct(){         
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('catalogomodel');
        $this->load->library('img');
    }

    /**
     * Documentation for foo.
     */
    public function foo(){
        ..some code..
    }
}
/* End of file catalogo.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/catalogo.php */
```

Comment: +1 For a great answer. I was led here by my own bug which, for future users, was that I began my comments with `/***` (my IDE auto-completes that for me).